# How to edit the end of the XML document end in Qt (writeEndDocument)?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I write a small program address book, contacts stored in the xml file. Here is the part off the code

```
void new_engine::main_window::write_to_db(const QString& n, const QString& s)
{
    QFile m_db_file(m_db_path);
    QString t("User");
    m_db_file.open(QIODevice::Append);
    QXmlStreamWriter wxml(&m_db_file);
    wxml.setAutoFormatting(true);
    if(m_size == 1)
    {
        wxml.writeStartDocument();
        wxml.writeStartElement("Persons");
    }
    wxml.writeStartElement(t);
    QString id = QString::number(m_size);
    wxml.writeAttribute("id", id);
    wxml.writeTextElement("Name", n);
    wxml.writeTextElement("Surname", s);
    wxml.writeEndElement();
    wxml.writeEndDocument();
    m_db_file.close();
}
```

but the problem is that after the first contact of the tag file is closed. here is the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Persons>
    <User id="1">
        <Name>das</Name>
        <Surname>vcvx</Surname>
    </User>
</Persons>

<User id="2">
    <Name>eqwevxcv</Name>
    <Surname>xcvxcx</Surname>
</User>

<User id="3">
    <Name>das</Name>
    <Surname>dasdasd</Surname>
</User>
```

but it must be so

```
<Persons>
    <User id="1">
        <Name>das</Name>
        <Surname>vcvx</Surname>
    </User>

    <User id="2">
        <Name>eqwevxcv</Name>
        <Surname>xcvxcx</Surname>
    </User>

    <User id="3">
        <Name>das</Name>
        <Surname>dasdasd</Surname>
    </User>
</Persons>
```

How can we do this, after each new record will have to change document end ?

Comment: Have you run it through the debugger?  For starters you're calling wxml.writeEndDocument() when in fact it's not the end of the document.

Comment: a lot of time looking in the debugger, it's okay just do not know how to edit the end of the document that is  wxml.writeEndDocument(); .

Comment: My recommendation is to write the start of the document once, then proceed to loop through and begin to populate the user sections by calling the function.  After the loop is complete you should then close the document (somewhere outside of the function)

Comment: but how to add elements after document end install. Тhis is address book and there are always added / deleted items,  and here it is necessary to constantly change the end of the document.

Comment: If you need to read data and append additional information, you can take a look at this [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195486/how-adding-a-node-in-an-xml-file-with-qxmlstreamwriter/17197127#17197127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example:

```
void write_to_db(QXmlStreamWriter& writer, QString id, QString name, QString surname)
{
  writer.writeStartElement("User");
  writer.writeAttribute(QXmlStreamAttribute("id", id));

  writer.writeTextElement("Name", name);
  writer.writeTextElement("Surname", surname);

  writer.writeEndElement();
}

// This can be a file, or whatever iodevice your heart desires.
QString out;
QXmlStreamWriter writer(&out);
writer.writeStartDocument();
writer.writeStartElement("Persons");

write_to_db(writer, "1", "das", "vcvx");
write_to_db(writer, "2", "das", "vcvx");
write_to_db(writer, "3", "das", "vcvx");

writer.writeEndElement(); // Close <persons> tag
writer.writeEndDocument();
```

The output (using QXmlStreamWriter::setAutoFormatting/Indent):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Persons>
 <User id="1">
  <Name>das</Name>
  <Surname>vcvx</Surname>
 </User>
 <User id="2">
  <Name>das</Name>
  <Surname>vcvx</Surname>
 </User>
 <User id="3">
  <Name>das</Name>
  <Surname>vcvx</Surname>
 </User>
</Persons>
```